# Flatmap equivalent in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, flatmap

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*" -Include "*.coffee" | Select -propert FullName
```

This returns a list of all coffee script files in my project.

How can I transform this into a single list where the `.coffee` part is converted to `.js` and `.js.map`?

Example pseudocode output:

```
[ something.coffee, somethingelse.coffee ]
[ something.js, something.js.map, somethingelse.js, somethingelse.js.map]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `BaseName` property:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*" -Include "*.coffee" | Foreach-Object {
    '{0}.js' -f $_.BaseName
    '{0}.js.map' -f $_.BaseName    
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, however the question was more about what is the PowerShell equilevant for flat map, if you could open a bit on that.

Comment: Sorry, Im not familiar with flatmap but wanted to show you a "pure" PowerShell approach.

Comment: Well it is doing a flatmap. Flatmap is when you map something to a list of lists and than "flatten" the lists to a single list. Also minor point, it's not giving full paths anymore. :o

Comment: I don't know a builtin method for that, you probably have to iterate over your list using a foreach and do it yourself...

Comment: @RusinaRange there's no need for the concept of a flatmap in PowerShell, since a `ForEach-Object` scriptblock can return an unbounded number of values that'll get flattened automatically by the pipeline (as you can observe in Martins answer)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen but that's literally a flat map then, exactly what i was looking for :D

Comment: @MartinBrandl sure, you should maybe add Mathiases comment to your answer since it explains why/how this works.